# Console wont print - AllocConsole() issue

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, winapi, console

got a weird one today. I'm writing a piece of physics coursework that has to be multithreaded and networked. Not only do I have to perform some simply physics on 800 2D objects but there should be unique threads and peer-peer networking. I've got physics with a couple of bugs, and threading working and moving onto the networking.

But before I get to all that Ive got a weird problem. I'm using OpenGl to render the objects and screenspace and decided to easily debug the network code I'd like to print out error/status messages to the console to see whats happening as its running. I added the following to the constructor of the class that holds Main;

```
AllocConsole();
freopen("CONIN&", "r",stdin);
freopen("CONOUT&", "w",stdout);
freopen("CONOUT&", "w",stderr);
```

As per my understanding and those of others on the course who implemented it this way, I should be able to print out to the console now using

```
cout << "blarg" << endl;
```

Instead th console ends and a breakpoint will trigger when placed on the cout luine but nothing is being printed by the console :(

kind regards,
Simon Johnson

Comment: As a start, I think the names are `"CONIN$"`, etc, not `"CONIN&"`. [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/search/en-us?query=CONIN%26&x=0&y=0&ac=8)

Comment: Thanks! Such a stupid issue in the end and now my wordy explanation is useless!